# model specification with glmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am attempting to set up a GLMM but am having problems expressing the hierarchical data structure in R with `glmer`. My data has the following structure:

```
y (dependent variable);
visit (L1: nested independent variable);
year  (L2: nested independent variable);
site  (L3: independent variable);
```

where `visit` is nested within `year`, which is nested within `site` (i.e. there may be up to 5 visits per year, of which there may be up to 10 years of data, per site).

I am interested in the effect of `year` upon `y`, while also wishing to treat `site` as a random effect (i.e. the intercepts and slopes [over year] vary by site).

I used the following command:

```
model <- glmer(y ~ year + (year | site) + (visit|year), 
               family=poisson, data=data)
```

Have I expressed the model correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would recommend

```
model <- glmer(y ~ year + 
                   (1+year | site) + 
                   (1|visit:site:year),
               family=poisson, data=data)
```

I recommend that you treat year as a numeric (continuous) variable; otherwise the `(year|site)` term will try to estimate among-site variances for every year, as well as the year-to-year covariances (which will probably fail). In this model,

- `year` specifies the overall, fixed linear trend with respect to year;
- `1+year|site` specifies variation in intercept among sites (i.e. overall count), as well as variation in the slope with respect to year among sites, and the slope-intercept correlation;
- `1|visit:site:year` gives an observation-level random effect, which allows for overdispersion.

There are other possible ways to slice this (you could consider a `(1|year)` term which accounts for overall, across-site varation around the linear trend with respect to year).

In general I would be careful with `(var|grp)` terms where `var` is categorical, because they will lead to estimating quite complex models if `var` has more than 2 or 3 levels ...